# Is it possible to show custom Image in x-axis label of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I draw a dendrogram and want to show small images on my x-axis labels instead of names, I'm not sure weather it is possible or not. 
My dendrogram is as 
[image: dendrogram]

and code of my Dendrogram is as

```
plt.figure(figsize=(25, 10))
plt.title('Hierarchical Clustering Dendrogram')
plt.xlabel('sample index')
plt.ylabel('distance')
dendrogram(
    Z,
    leaf_rotation=90.,  # rotates the x axis labels
    leaf_font_size=8.,  # font size for the x axis labels
     labels= templateNames

)
plt.show()
```

Right now I'm showing images Names, but I also have list of images that are saved another array. I've tried `plt.imgshow(img)` but It does't work.

Comment: this is not relevant to my question. these are simple drawing and I am trying to draw image in dendrogram want to replace lebel

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8745727/4124317) gives you exactly what you need.