# How to use a colored shape as yticks in matplotlib or seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I am working on a task called knowledge tracing which estimates the student mastery level over time. I would like to plot a similar figure as below using the Matplotlib or Seaborn.

[image: image1: Target result]

It uses different colors to represent a knowledge concept, instead of a text. However, I have googled and found there is no article is talking about how we can do this.

I tried the following

```py
# simulate a record of student mastery level
student_mastery = np.random.rand(5, 30)
df = pd.DataFrame(student_mastery)

# plot the heatmap using seaborn
marker = matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle(marker='o', fillstyle='full')
sns_plot = sns.heatmap(df, cmap="RdYlGn", vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0)
y_limit = 5
y_labels = [marker for i in range(y_limit)]
plt.yticks(range(y_limit), y_labels)
```

Yet it simply returns the `__repr__` of the marker, e.g., `<matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle at 0x1c5bb07860>` on the yticks.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make the xtick labels of a plot be simple drawings using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733558/how-can-i-make-the-xtick-labels-of-a-plot-be-simple-drawings-using-matplotlib)

Comment: If you answer the question inside the question, what's the question?

Comment: Oh, it is my first time to post a question in the stackoverflow, I don't know that I shouldn't post the solution I did finally afterward. I have removed the answer. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While [How can I make the xtick labels of a plot be simple drawings using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733558/how-can-i-make-the-xtick-labels-of-a-plot-be-simple-drawings-using-matplotlib) gives you a general solution for arbitrary shapes, for the shapes shown here, it may make sense to use unicode symbols as text and colorize them according to your needs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(np.random.rand(3,10), cmap="Greys")

symbolsx = ["⚪", "⚪", "⚫", "⚫", "⚪", "⚫","⚪", "⚫", "⚫","⚪"]
colorsx = np.random.choice(["#3ba1ab", "#b43232", "#8ecc3a", "#893bab"], 10)
ax.set_xticks(range(len(symbolsx)))
ax.set_xticklabels(symbolsx, size=40)
for tick, color in zip(ax.get_xticklabels(), colorsx):
    tick.set_color(color)

symbolsy = ["◾", "◾", "◾"]
ax.set_yticks(range(len(symbolsy)))
ax.set_yticklabels(symbolsy, size=40)
for tick, color in zip(ax.get_yticklabels(), ["crimson", "gold", "indigo"]):
    tick.set_color(color)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works! I really appreciate your method of using unicode symbols as text and colorize.